# Unix Server unreachable, but responding to ping

Tags: solaris

I'm unable to login to my Solaris box, but its responding to ping when I do

```
ping hostname
```

I see the following messages under /var/adm/messages

```
FATAL 2035: sslgets - SSL_read error - error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
Communication time out to seosd. Executing seosd 
Communication time out to seosd. Executing seosd
```

Comment: The logs you posted are from the Solaris box you are trying to SSH to?

Comment: Are you running any kind of identity management or SSO solution on that box? If so, could you post product and configuration details as well?

Comment: ssh to my application server...

Comment: So...? Are you intending to add the information requested?

Comment: I need to know what caused the server to go unreachable... and is there any way we can get alerted when the server goes unreachable?

Comment: Yes syneticon-dj

Answer (score 0):

Since you were able to post a snippit from /var/adm/messages, I'm assuming you have a way to login to the server other than ssh.

**1)** Verify the SSH service (daemon) is running

`ps -ef | grep sshd`

**2)** Verify the Solaris server is able to resolve hostnames

`nslookup the_name_of_your_workstation`

**3)** Verify that the Solaris server is able to ping the workstation you are trying to ssh from.

`ping the_name_of_your_workstation`

**NOTE:** Replace `the_name_of_your_workstation` with the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) of the system you are trying to ssh *from*. If you are unable to find the FQDN of your workstation, please contact your internal support team.